# Sitecore 301 Redirect or IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewrite

I am working on Sitecore project and using 301 redirect for our website. Right now our redirect chain is

http://example.com/ >> http://www.example.com >> https://www.example.com >> https://www.example.com/en

Our company recommendation is to change it in one redirect Example.

http://example.com/ >> https://www.example.com/en

http://www.example.com >> https://www.example.com/en

https://www.example.com >> https://www.example.com/en

Is there any way that I can achieve this requirement with Sitecore or IIS URL Rewrite? If yes then How? Thank you for any small help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, You can achieve this requirement through Sitecore 301 Redirect Module or IIS URL Rewrite both.

Paste the below Code inside your `<system.webServer></system.webServer>` element in the web.config

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect Maps Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{StaticRedirects:{PATH_INFO}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="True" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="StaticRedirects">
      <add key="http://example.com" value="https://www.example.com/en" />
<add key="http://www.example.com" value="https://www.example.com/en" />
<add key="https://www.example.com" value="https://www.example.com/en" />

    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Below is the link, from where you can easily generate the IIS 301 redirection rules online :

http://iis7-rewrite.herokuapp.com

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 9):

Well in any case you will have to bind example.com as well as www.example.com on your website.

Next you have multiple options. Either use IIS Rewrite rules.

```
<rule name="Root Hit Force HTTPS Redirection" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

and for www redirection

```
<rule name="Redirect example.com to www" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Another possibility is to use the redirect module that comes with SXA.

And finally, you could use something from the marketplace.
https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/3/301_Redirect_module.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own re-write rule:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

It is not related to the Sitecore. If you want to handle inside the Sitecore, you have to use rewrite rule module available on the Sitecore Marketplace.